# Access object properties in Telerik client templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-mvc

My column is bound to an Employee object like this:

```
class Employee
{
    int Id;
    string Name;
}
```

My edit template presents this column as a drop-down box with the options populated by ajax binding (I need to do it this way because the options will change depending on other column selections by the user).

```
@(Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
    .Name("Employee")
    .CascadeTo("Order")
    .DataBinding(binding => binding.Ajax().Select("GetEmployees", "Order")))
```

However, the column keeps displaying the Employee.Id value.  I got around this by defining a server-side display template to show Employee.Name instead.

Now I'm trying to enable InCell editing and it looks like I can only use client-side display templates (which makes sense).  But how do I access the Name property?

I've tried this, which gives me the Id...

```
columns.Bound(o => o.Employee).Title("Employee")
    .ClientTemplate("<text><#= Employee #></text>");
```

...this, which gives me an empty string...

```
columns.Bound(o => o.Employee).Title("Employee")
    .ClientTemplate("<text><#= Employee.Name #></text>");
```

...and this, which gives me an error

```
columns.Bound(o => o.Employee).Title("Employee")
    .ClientTemplate("<text><#= Name #></text>");
```

Any way I can get my Employee cell to display like how I want?

Comment: It's really strange that columns.Bound(o => o.Employee).Title("Employee")
    .ClientTemplate("<text><#= Employee #></text>"); returns you the id. HOw does your action method which servers the Grid with data look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the properties on the bound object by using the <# > syntax

```
columns.Bound(c => c.Name).ClientTemplate("<input id='<# Name #>' />);
```